# Best method to check if a point lies on an arc in c#

Tags: c#, automatic-ref-counting, point

What I want to do should be simple but it has been a while since I studied math.

Let's say I have `Point` and `Arc` classes as below. How can I check if the Point `p` lies on Arc `a`.

```
public class Point
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

public class Arc
{
    public double Radius;
    public double StartAngle;
    public double EndAngle;

    // center of the arc
    public double Xc;
    public double Yc;
}


Point p = new Point() { X = 5, Y = 5 };
Arc a = new Arc()
{
    Radius = 5,
    StartAngle = 0,
    EndAngle = Math.PI/2,
    Xc = 0,
    Yc = 0
};
```

Comment: @Servy It is about how to implement this in C#.

Comment: Once you solve the geometry problem of creating a formula that solves this problem *then* it becomes a programming problem of implementing that formula.  Finding that formula is a geometry problem, not a programming problem.  I imagine that once you've solved the geometry problem, implementing that in C# should be trivial, and I would not foresee a need to ask about it on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this answer which is posted here for future reference. I know it is not the most efficient method but it does the job.

```
// first check if the point is on a circle with the radius of the arc. 
// Next check if it is between the start and end angles of the arc.
public static bool IsPointOnArc(Point p, Arc a)
{
    if (p.Y * p.Y == a.Radius * a.Radius - p.X * p.X)
    {
        double t = Math.Acos(p.X / a.Radius);
        if (t >= a.StartAngle && t <= a.EndAngle)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You will need the point relative to the center of the arc. Then you will need to check the sign of d.y, if negative then pi should be added to the result of acos